# "Биологически()активный" — слитно или раздельно?

Tags: орфография, слитно-раздельно

Может, это вопрос уже задавали. Меня озадачило слово или словосочетание "биологически()активный". В тексте написано раздельно, но у меня возникло сомнение. Например, похожее слово "слабохарактерный" ведь пишется слитно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что же получится, если Вы напишете отдельно? ХарАктерный (как?) слабо?!  Слабохарактерный  - это одно слово, прилагательное, образованное от подчинительного словосочетания (слабый характер), поэтому пишется слитно. Биологически активный - это сочетание прилагательного с наречием. Наречие в данном словосочетании обозначает направление активности.

Comment: А бывает слабо характерный и мало характерный (с ударением на е)?